# Is there a way to connect two Docker containers and the host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm facing some issues with the communication of the containers.

My FE app users server side and client side rendering.

When I visit in the browser (FE) http://localhost:3000 and send an AJAX request to http://localhost:4000 (BE), I am able to connect. This is the client side part that works.

But when I reload the page, this is where the server side part jumps in. FE can NOT connect to BE anymore.

I guess this is because localhost:4000 is not reachable from within the FE container, right?

I've tried to assign static IPs to the containers, but that did not work either.

I would appreciate your help. I'm kind of lost at this point. Thanks!

```
version: '3'

services:
    be:
        image: node:10-alpine
        volumes:
            - ../test1/be:/var/www/app/be
        expose:
            - 4000
        ports:
            - '4000:4000'
        working_dir: '/var/www/app/be'
        command: /bin/sh -c "npm install && npm run docker"
        networks:
          - default

    fe:
        image: node:10-alpine
        volumes:
          - ./fe:/var/www/app/fe
        expose:
          - 3000
        ports:
          - '3000:3000'
        working_dir: '/var/www/app/fe'
        command: /bin/sh -c "npm install && npm run docker"
        networks:
          - default

networks:
    default:
```

Comment: you need to use proxy server like ngnix

Comment: try this repo, you will have all the idea what to do and how to do https://github.com/dupinder/NgnixDockerizedDevEnv

Comment: Can you directly run the two processes with Node on the host?  (What benefits are you getting from using Docker here?)  Is your `fe` container both directly calling the `be` container and also producing client-side code that needs to call it?  (The URLs will be different for those two calls in several common setups, not just in Docker.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving the issue.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    traefik:
        restart: always
        container_name: traefik
        image: traefik:latest
        command:
            - --api.insecure=true
            - --api.dashboard=true
            - --api.debug=true
            - --log.level=DEBUG
            - --providers.docker=true
            - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
            - --providers.docker.network=web
            - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
        labels:
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`traefik.localhost`)"
            - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
        ports: 
            - '80:80'
            - '8080:8080'
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        networks:
            - web

    be:
        restart: always
        container_name: be
        image: node:10-alpine
        volumes:
            - ./be:/var/www/app/be
        expose:
            - 80
        working_dir: '/var/www/app/be'
        command: /bin/sh -c "npm install && npm run docker"
        labels:
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.http.routers.be-web.rule=Host(`be.localhost`)"
            - "traefik.http.routers.be-web.entrypoints=web"
        depends_on:
            - traefik
        networks:
            - web

    fe:
        restart: always
        container_name: fe
        image: node:10
        volumes:
          - ./fe:/var/www/app/fe
        expose: 
            - 80
        working_dir: '/var/www/app/fe'
        command: /bin/sh -c "npm install && npm run docker"
        labels:
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.http.routers.fe-web.rule=Host(`fe.localhost`)"
            - "traefik.http.routers.fe-web.entrypoints=web"
        depends_on:
            - traefik
            - be
        links:
            - 'be:be.localhost'
        networks:
            - web

networks:
    web:
        external: true
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I used to communicate Front End application and backend application is `Ngnix reverse proxy`

If you visit this repo, Readme.md has described all the things that you need to know
https://github.com/dupinder/NgnixDockerizedDevEnv

Basic idea is

```
server {    
    listen 80;  
    server_name host.docker.internal;   

    # By default land on localhost:80 to root so in root we copied UI build to the ngnix html dir.
    # have a look to docker-compose uiapp service.
    location / {    
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;   
            index  index.html index.htm;    
    }   

   # after location add filter, from which every endpoint starts with or comes in endpoint 
   # so that ngnix can capture the URL and reroute it.
   # like /backend/getUserInfo/<UserId> 
   # In above example /backend is that filter which will be captured by Ngnix and reroute the flow.
    location /backend { 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;    
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;  
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #proxy_pass http://<ContainerName>:<PortNumber>; 
        # In our case Container name is as we setup in docker-compose `beservice` and port 8080
        proxy_pass http://beservice:8080;   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dupinder-singh but , I implemented that now, but with your solution I still I can't reach http://ui-app from my computer. Because inside the docker container "ui-app" exits but in my local it points to localhost not to ui-app. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is you UI application even running or crashed, if crashed then please share the error

Comment: ```
1189a5b1b9be        nginx:1-alpine      "/docker-entrypoint.…"   4 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp       nginx
669c41b80a3b        node:10             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   25 minutes ago      Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   fe
2dd74c4f12ef        node:10-alpine      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   54 minutes ago      Up 14 seconds       0.0.0.0:4000->4000/tcp   be
```

My UI app is not crashed, it just can't make server side requests to localhost (nginx)

Comment: let me ask the question slightly different... How can I access http://fe:3000 or http://be:3000 from my browser?

Comment: okay what changes did you make in Nginx for reverse proxy. Or can you please share your docker-compose and docker file

Comment: BTW don't use `localhost` use container name instead of `localhost`, because docker resolve internal IP address using container name